# How to get the log of a single commit without the diff

Tags: git

I want the `git log` of a single commit but without the diff.

So far this is the simplest solution:

```
git log -1 <commit>
```

It looks like I want the `-<number>` switch. From the man page:

```
-<number>, -n <number>, --max-count=<number>
    Limit the number of commits to output.
```

This is not an exact duplicate of either of the listed questions.

Comment: The second answer of the question you linked yourself should help you to figure out how to get any result…

Comment: My original question was poorly worded. As it is now, this question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=%B <treeish>
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was poorly worded. I also want the commit, Author, and Date.

Comment: Look under "PRETTY FORMATS" at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%h %ad %s (%an)'
```

**OR**

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s"
```